# How do I add a 3rd column to the below to show the most recent date before the max date? So the final output is a 3 column table grouped by user_id?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

This is the snipped that shows the latest purchase date.
max(purchase_date) - 1 is what I need, both of them being displayed side by side.

```
select  order.user_id, order.purchase_date
from orders
join
(select id, max(purchase_date) as max_date 
from orders
group by id) o2

on orders.user_id = o2.user_id and 
orders.purchase_date = o2.max_date
```

Comment: Select one definite DBMS - their syntax differs. Also use CTE with window function instead of the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

--I believe the follow code should work both PostgreSQL and MySQL.

```
with a as(
    select  order.user_id,
            order.purchase_date,
            max(purchase_date) over(partition by user_id)
    from orders order by purchase_date desc
)
select a.*,
       lag(purchase_date,1) 
    over (order by purchase_date desc) as previously_order_date from a;
```

> lag ( value anycompatible [, offset integer [, default anycompatible
> ]] ) → anycompatible
>
> Returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows before the
> current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead
> returns default (which must be of a type compatible with value). Both
> offset and default are evaluated with respect to the current row. If
> omitted, offset defaults to 1 and default to NULL.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html

PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html
MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: Thanks for replying! 

I need the second column to show NULL unless there is a previous date. (if user has had only one order, I only want that displayed in the max(col))

Comment: update my answer, you can based on my answer then customize it.